# getting value from textbox doesn't give a single line string?

Tags: javascript, textbox

Here is my code. I am using role="textbox" and getting value from it. But, when I enter more than one line of text in the textbox, it gives me the value in multiple lines. How do I get this value in a single line?

```js
function getText() {
  let text = document.querySelector('[role=textbox]').innerText;
  alert(text);
}
```

```css
.textbox{
border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div id="txtboxLabel">Enter your five-digit zipcode</div>
    <button onclick=getText()>
    Get TextBox Data
    </button>
    <div class="textbox" role="textbox" contenteditable="true" aria-labelledby="txtboxLabel"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace all `\n` (new line character that causes the multi line) with space character from the text content using [`String.prototype.replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll):

```js
function getText() {
  let text = document.querySelector('[role=textbox]').innerText.replaceAll('\n',' ');
  alert(text);
}
```

```css
.textbox{
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div id="txtboxLabel">Enter your five-digit zipcode</div>
    <button onclick=getText()>
    Get TextBox Data
    </button>
    <div class="textbox" role="textbox" contenteditable="true" aria-labelledby="txtboxLabel"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace all the new line characters *\n* by using Strings *replaceAll()*

```
text = text.replaceAll('\n', "");
```

```js
function getText() {
  let text = document.querySelector('[role=textbox]').innerText;
  text = text.replaceAll('\n', "");
  alert(text);
}
```

```css
.textbox{
border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div id="txtboxLabel">Enter your five-digit zipcode</div>
    <button onclick=getText()>
    Get TextBox Data
    </button>
    <div class="textbox" role="textbox" contenteditable="true" aria-labelledby="txtboxLabel"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Complicated to understand but this can do the trick by replacing all return at the line by space.

```
function getText() {
  let text = document.querySelector('[role=textbox]').innerText;
  text = text.split("\n").join(" ");
  alert(text);
}
```

If you want only the first line:

```
function getText() {
  let text = document.querySelector('[role=textbox]').innerText;
  text = text.split("\n")[0];
  alert(text);
}
```